# Why doesn't this trigger a stack overflow on Ubuntu inside WSL?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, stack, stack-overflow

```
#include <iostream>
 
int main()
{
    constexpr size_t array_size{1000000000};
    int stack[array_size];
    std::cout << sizeof(stack);
    return 0;
}
```

The program just prints out 4000000000. So seems like this should require almost 4GB of memory, significantly more than the 8MB that I thought was the stack size for Ubuntu. I am running this inside WSL in case that matters.

One idea is that it might be optimized. So I updated the program like this:

```
#include <iostream>
 
int main()
{
    constexpr size_t array_size{1000000000};
    int stack[array_size];
    for(size_t i{0}; i<array_size; i++)
        stack[i] = i;

    std::cout << sizeof(stack);
    return 0;
}
```

Takes a bit longer to run then outputs 4000000000.

It appears that this is necessary to trigger the overflow:

```
#include <iostream>
 
int main()
{
    constexpr size_t array_size{1000000000};
    int stack[array_size];
    stack[0] = 0;
    for(size_t i{1}; i<array_size; i++)
        stack[i] = stack[i-1] + 1;

    std::cout << sizeof(stack) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Last element: " << stack[array_size - 1] << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Interesting idea. I tried to update the code to initialize the array and I am getting the same result. Will update the question.

Comment: Does not change any observable result (https://godbolt.org/z/qGzYo6). Make a program where you print the sum of all elements and see then. Also try to compile with optimization off.

Comment: Yeah indeed, that seems to be the case. Looks like you need to do something that isn't so easy to optimize away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The program is (most probably) optimized to just show the size and no memory is actually allocated. This is allowed in accordance with the *[as-if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if)* rule.

Here are examples where you can compare the [unoptimized](https://godbolt.org/z/3nsY78) (crashes) with the [optimized](https://godbolt.org/z/fMfb9c) (prints `4000000000`) results.

Comment: You're right. I tried another unoptimized version where I output the last element and that crashed. Didn't realize C++ is optimized to this level, pretty awesome. Thanks.